# header-footer configuring

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, fancyhdr

Need to start page numbering from the n-th page (in this case 6); used `ifthen` and `fancyhdr` packages. So, no dotted lines since page 6 and page 5 is already numbered.

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\ifthenelse{\value{page}<6}
{
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}
{
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox
to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox
to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}
}
```

Any guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because your `\ifthenelse` statement is evaluated only once at the beginning of the document where page number is less than 6 and so no header or footer are printed in all the document pages.

You need something that is evaluated at each page like the following code:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}

\def\mypage{\ifthenelse{\value{page}<6}{}{\thepage}}
\def\myrule{\ifthenelse{\value{page}<6}{}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}}

\cfoot{\mypage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\myrule}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\myrule}
```

Comment: works fine! thx, man!